# problem with # and get

Tags: php, get

i'm trying to send data via GET and one of the fields has the sign # in it (sometimes more than once).
 
Is there a way to encode or escape the # in the GET so i can be able to send all my fields with GET ? (i can only send my data via GET, i'm not allowed to use POST)

thanks

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Yes, use `urlencode()` to ensure that they won't be a problem. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to send this field **to** PHP via `GET` (i.e. through AJAX) form the client side, use javascript's [`encodeURIComponent();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Else if you need to make a `GET` request from your server to another server, use [`CURL`](http://php.net/curl), it will do the encoding for you.

And in the case that you just want to output a hyper reference (link) then use the other answers provided (now deleted, referenced [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)).